# Enumerating Graphs with Self-Loops

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Brendan McKay has already done the work for finding all non-isomorphic graphs of n variables that can be found here (under Simple Graphs): http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html

I believe this was done using polya enumeration, which I understand the basics of. I would like to expand on this, and allow self loops in these graphs. So, i'd like to find all non-ismorphic graphs of n variables, including self loops. This will be directly used for another part of my code and provide a massive optimization. I'm just not quite sure how to go about it.

To be clear, Brendan Mckay's files give all non ismorphic graphs, ie in edge notation,

1-2 1-3

is a graph with an edge between vertex 1 and 2, and 1 and 3. I want this list to also include self loops, ie:

1-2 1-3 1-1

or

1-2 1-3 1-1 2-2

I want the minimum number of graphs, so all non-ismorphic ones. How can I go about finding them, hopefully using the data Brendan McKay has available for simple graphs?

Answer (score 6):

This can indeed be done with the Polya Enumeration Theorem. There is a
very simple yet powerful observation that can be made here: if we have
the cycle index of the edge permutation group induced by the action of
the  symmetric group  on the  vertices, the  cycle index  of the  edge
permutation group including self-loops  can be obtained by multiplying
the factorizations  into disjoint cycles  of the edge  permutation and
the original  vertex permutation and  sum these contributions  for all
vertex permutations. (Of course we  work directly with the cycle index
of the  symmetric group  which is much  more efficient  than iterating
over all  permutations.) But the  cycle index of the  edge permutation
group is not difficult to compute, the  code can be found at this [MSE
Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314103/how-many-2-edge-colourings-of-k-n-are-there).

This gives the  following cycle indices for the  enumeration of graphs
that may have self-loops: for $n=2$ we have

$$1/2\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}+1/2\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}},$$
for $n=3$ we get
$$1/6\,{a_{{1}}}^{6}+1/2\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{2}
+1/3\,{a_{{3}}}^{2},$$
and finally for $n=4$ we obtain
$$1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{10}+1/4\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{3}+
1/3\,{a_{{3}}}^{3}a_{{1}}+1/8\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{4}
+1/4\,a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}.$$

As an example we substitute $1+z$ into the cycle index for $n=3$ to get
$${z}^{6}+2\,{z}^{5}+4\,{z}^{4}+6\,{z}^{3}+4\,{z}^{2}+2\,z+1.$$

There are indeed two graphs on  three vertices with $1$ edge including
loops, namely a single edge or a single loop. Similarly there are four
graphs with  $2$ edges, namely  two loops, two  edges, an edge  with a
loop on one end and an edge that is opposed to a vertex with a loop on
it. Furthermore the  six graphs with three edges are:  a triangle with
no loops, a fork with a loop on  the handle, a fork with a loop on one
of its  ends, a  line segment  with two  loops at  either end,  a line
segment with  a loop on one  end and a  loop not incident on  the line
segment, and finally, three loops. It goes on like this.

These   cycle  indices   produce   the  following   total  counts   of
non-isomorphic undirected graphs with possible self-loops present:

```
1
6
20
90
544
5096
79264
2208612
113743760
10926227136
1956363435360
652335084592096
405402273420996800
470568642161119963904
1023063423471189431054720
4178849203082023236058229792
32168008290073542372004082199424
468053896898117580623237189908861696
12908865186281154904787051023018388368640
676599895346467962508983189158040730734206464
67557268911383303274368343026941404659790140175872
12878644470123443279570180725329554086442149175832124416
4696891990987444795146988875290693218960182452250871238964224
3283275444870880220030739747435965751837707129958501790119044590592
4406671511641658245922265014648856899986657018190959680004287879813376000
11374011362523188765310166602160674880959112891073505609667787021125321629659136
```

This     sequence     of     values     points     us     to     [OEIS
A000666](https://oeis.org/A000666) where a  large amount of additional
material can be found.

For those who are  curious to see the details, here  is the Maple code
to compute these values:

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local l;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_cycleind_edg_loops :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local all, term, termvars, res, l1, l2, inst1, u, v,
    uidx, vidx;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;
    if n=1 then return a[1]; fi;

    all := 0:
    for term in pet_cycleind_symm(n) do
        termvars := indets(term); res := 1;

        # edges on different cycles of different sizes
        for uidx to nops(termvars) do
            u := op(uidx, termvars);
            l1 := op(1, u);

            for vidx from uidx+1 to nops(termvars) do
                v := op(vidx, termvars);
                l2 := op(1, v);

                res := res *
                a[lcm(l1, l2)]
                ^((l1*l2/lcm(l1, l2))*
                  degree(term, u)*degree(term, v));
            od;
        od;

        # edges on different cycles of the same size
        for u in termvars do
            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            # a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1*l1/l1)
            res := res *
            a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1);
        od;

        # edges on identical cycles of some size
        for u in termvars do
            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            if type(l1, odd) then
                # a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-1)/l1);
                res := res *
                (a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-1)))^inst1;
            else
                # a[l1/2]^(l1/2/(l1/2))*a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-2)/l1)
                res := res *
                (a[l1/2]*a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-2)))^inst1;
            fi;
        od;

        all := all + term*res;
    od;

    all;
end;


pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res, k;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

VGF :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local ind;

    ind := pet_cycleind_edg_loops(n);
    expand(pet_varinto_cind(1+z, ind));
end;

COUNT :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local q;

    subs([seq(a[q]=2, q=1..n*(n+1)/2)],
         pet_cycleind_edg_loops(n));
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The quick-and-dirty method would be to add self-loops in all possible ways for each graph, and check which of them are isomorphic.

A more sophisticated way will first calculate the automorphism group of the graph, and use that data to solve your problem. That can save a lot of time since for most graphs, the automorphism group is trivial.

McKay's library can check whether two graphs are isomorphic, and I think it also calculates the automorphism group (at least in some sense). At the very least, you should be able to use the quick-and-dirty method only for graphs with non-trivial automorphism group.

Comment: I'm pretty sure his nauty program doesn't recognize self loops, so i'm not really sure if it will be of much help in this case.

Comment: You could code it though, say by connecting each vertex with a self-loop to a large star.

Comment: nauty can work with coloured graphs, however, so we can use one colour for loopy nodes and another colour for loop-free nodes.