# What is the number of set partitions of $\{1,1,2,2,3,3\}$?

Tags: combinatorics

It must be less than $B_6$ (where $B_6$ is the Bell number of $6$) since the  elements are "duplicated".   I would most appreciate a generating function that gives the number of set partitions of $\{1,1,2,2, ...n,n\}$.

Comment: What kind of thing is $\{1,1,2,2,3,3\}$ here? I assume it's not a set, because that would be equal to $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: {1,1,2,2,3,3} is a multiset.

Comment: Using the Polya Enumeration Theorem twice in an algorithm with rather poor complexity I get the sequence $$2, 9, 66, 712, 10457,\ldots$$ which is [OEIS A020555](https://oeis.org/A020555). The references therein may prove useful reading if indeed this is your sequence. They have a generating function for efficient calculation of these numbers.

Comment: The formula that I used is $$[B_1^2\cdots B_n^2] \sum_{q=1}^{2n} Z(S_q)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n} Z(S_k) (B_1+\cdots + B_n) \right),$$ which has limited utility for actual computations.

Comment: The first comment in the OEIS entry would appear to confirm that this sequence is a match.

Comment: The definition from the OEIS which says that we count multigraphs with $n$ labeled edges means that the vertices of the graph represent the multisets of the multiset partition and are connected by an edge $k$ if the two instances of the value $k$ are included in the sets represented by the two vertices that constitute the edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using  the hint  given in  the OEIS  entry we  can write  an optimized
program that  makes it  possible to compute  the sequence  in question
even for large values of $n$ for example this segment:

$$2, 9, 66, 712, 10457, 198091, 4659138, 132315780, 4441561814,
\\ 173290498279, 7751828612725,393110572846777, 22385579339430539, 
\\ 1419799938299929267, 99593312799819072788,
\ldots $$

The aforementioned  hint says that we can  equivalently count
multigraphs with  $n$ labeled  edges where the  vertices of  the graph
represent the multisets of the multiset partition and are connected by
an edge $k$ if the two instances  of the value $k$ are included in the
sets represented by the two vertices that constitute the edge.

Supposing that we  have the cycle index $Z(G_n)$ of  the action on the
edges of  the symmetric  group permuting the  $n$ vertices of  a graph
where loops  are allowed the desired  value is thus given  by ($2n$ is
the maximum number of vertices we can cover with the $n$ labeled edges
and these  are multi-edges so they  may be labeled with  any subset of
the $n$ labels)

$$[B_1 B_2 \cdots B_n] Z(G_{2n})
\left(\prod_{q=1}^n (1+B_q)\right).$$

But this  cycle index  is easy to  compute with the  computation being
documented at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41386/).

Observe  that  we  have  a  special  case  here  that  admits  radical
simplification. Suppose we have a term $\alpha\in Z(G_{2n})$ which has
the form $$p(\alpha) \prod_k a_k^{j_k(\alpha)}$$

with  $p(\alpha)$  being  the   leading  coefficient  (a  number)  and
$j_k(\alpha)$ the degree of $a_k$ in $\alpha.$

Now  we have  that  any possible  factors  $a_k$ where  $k\gt 1$  only
contribute  through the constant  term because  we are  extracting the
product $B_1 B_2\cdots B_n.$ This leaves
$$p(\alpha) a_1^{j_1(\alpha)}.$$

Finally observe that
$$[B_1 B_2\cdots B_n] 
\left(\prod_{q=1}^n (1+B_q)\right)^{j_1(\alpha)}
\\ = [B_1 B_2\cdots B_n] 
\prod_{q=1}^n (1+B_q)^{j_1(\alpha)}
= \prod_{q=1}^n {j_1(\alpha)\choose 1}
= j_1(\alpha)^n.$$

The key effect here is  that we have eliminated costly exponentiations
of  multivariate  polynomials  and  are  only  working  with  numbers,
computing this value:
$$\sum_{\alpha\in Z(G_{2n})} p(\alpha) j_1(\alpha)^n.$$

This is the code:

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
local p, s;
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_flatten_term :=
proc(varp)
local terml, d, cf, v;

    terml := [];

    cf := varp;
    for v in indets(varp) do
        d := degree(varp, v);
        terml := [op(terml), seq(v, k=1..d)];
        cf := cf/v^d;
    od;

    [cf, terml];
end;


pet_cycleind_edg :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local s, t, res, cycs, l1, l2, flat, u, v;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    s := 0:
    for t in pet_cycleind_symm(n) do
        flat := pet_flatten_term(t);

        cycs := flat[2]; res := 1;

        for u to nops(cycs) do
            for v from u+1 to nops(cycs) do
                l1 := op(1, cycs[u]); l2 := op(1, cycs[v]);
                res := res * a[lcm(l1, l2)]^(l1*l2/lcm(l1, l2));
            od;
        od;

        for u to nops(cycs) do
            l1 := op(1, cycs[u]);
            if type(l1, odd) then
                # a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-1)/l1);
                res := res*a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-1));
            else
                # a[l1/2]^(l1/2/(l1/2))*a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-2)/l1)
                res := res*a[l1/2]*a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-2));
            fi;
        od;

        s := s + res*t;
    od;

    s;
end;



Q :=
proc(n)
option remember;
    local res, flat, term;

    res := 0;
    for term in pet_cycleind_edg(2*n) do
        flat := pet_flatten_term(term);
        res := res + flat[1]*degree(term, a[1])^n;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

Comment: I am very grateful for and interested in your reply.  I am taking a final exam in two days so I cannot review your post right away.

Comment: Supposing that we have the cycle index Z(Gn) of the action on the edges of the symmetric group permuting the n vertices of a graph where loops are allowed.

Comment: I can generate the cycle indices Z(G_n) for small values of n on Mathematica.  I do not understand how your Polya substitution formula ( the first formula in your post) would count the number of labeled multigraphs.

Comment: Maybe it would help if I tell you the only thing that I do understand:  If I substitute 1/(1 - x^i) in Z(G_3) for example.  I get  the number of multigraphs with loops on 3 vertices.  1 + 2 x + 6 x^2 + 14 x^3 + 28 x^4 + 52 x^5 + 93 x^6 + ...

Comment: Good observation. The formula that you ask about is of the same type. Note that $$\prod_{q=1}^n (1+B_q)$$ generates all sets of labels (choose between it being included or not included) and a multi-edge has full symmetry between the constituent single edges so we are effectively dealing with a set. Now if we were to omit the coefficient extractor we would get all multigraphs with $n$ types of labels on the edges where off edges are admitted (constant coefficient). Hence after we apply the coeffcient extractor we get those graphs with exactly one instance of each type.

Comment: It may help to subsitute e,g. $\prod_{q=1}^3 (1+B_q)$ into e.g. $Z(G_3)$ with a CAS and verify the result using total enumeration with pen and paper. That should make things clear quite quickly.

Comment: OK Thank you!  I think I understand this now.  Here is a question to check my understanding.  I made the substitution into Z(G_3) as you suggest above and I did verify that there are 66 multiset partitions of {1,1,2,2,3,3}.  Now, if I want to know the number multiset partitons of {1,1,1,2,2,3,3}, I just find the coefficient of B_1^2*B_2*B_3   right? There are 355 of them. right?

Comment: No, now on second thought I think my statement is wrong.  I am trying to think of how we could interpret the other coefficients of in Z(G_3)((1+B_1)(1+B_2)(1+B_3).

Comment: The above gadget can only be used to compute multiset partitions where each element occurs twice. This is because the concept of an edge is wired into the gadget to represent two instances of a given value, which are included in the multisets represented by the two end points. For your question you may use the poor complexity formula that I worked with initially. It is possible to construct a gadget for multisets where each element occurs three times and so on although the cycle indices require a CAS.

Comment: Yes! Thank you.  I agree.  I will make this claim then as as an example of the iterpretation of the coefficients in Z(G_2n)( (1+B_1)(1+B_2)(1+B_3)).  The coefficient of B_1^j*B_2^k*B_3^m is the number of multigraphs with loops (with an infinite number of nodes)  having j red edges, k blue edges and m green edges where no more than one edge of like color joins any two (not necessarily distinct) vertices.